# Horizontal categories view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a list of categories. I'd like to add them in a horizontal scroll type view. But inturn i also want that the list contains only image and text of that category. And when i slide, it should directly come to an object of the list, it should not lie somewhere in the middle.
One object will almost cover the 
How should i do implement that?

Comment: you're going to need to be more specific.  Maybe draw a diagram or show some code... vague questions get vague answers.

Comment: ok.. i suspected that. I ll be more specific